# Can I transfer Mass Effect saved game files from my PC to my Xbox360?

Tags: pc, xbox-360, mass-effect-series

I played Mass Effect 1 & 2 on the PC. Unfortunately, my PC was barely able to run ME2 so I decided to purchase Mass Effect 3 for the Xbox 360.

Since I want to carryover the decisions I made in ME1 and ME2 is it possible to download or transfer a PC saved game to the Xbox?

Comment: Possible solution: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57205/convert-savegame-accross-platform

Answer (score 7):

[Gibbed's Mass Effect 2 Save Editor (Modified)](http://social.bioware.com/project/4373/#details) should allow you to convert save files between Xbox360 and PC formats.

[Here](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/103/index/2277020) are some instructions for moving the save files to and from the Xbox360.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the instructions? The forum you linked is down.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import Xbox360 Mass Effect 3 saves into gibbed - I tried it. I have previously found a converter but deleted it and I can't remember where I found it.

Comment: They want to convert PC saves to Xbox saves, not the other way