# Can PC saves be imported into console version of Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I transfer saved game files from my PC to my Xbox360?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53213/can-i-transfer-saved-game-files-from-my-pc-to-my-xbox360)

Having not yet played Mass Effect 1 or 2 I plan on purchasing them before jumping into Mass Effect 3. What platform I purchase a game for is larger dependent on where I'll be spending my time in the immediate future. For instance right now I'd probably buy Mass Effect 1 for the PC. A few months from now when I'm ready to jump into Mass Effect 2 I might purchase it for the Xbox 360.

Which brings me to my question can Mass Effect save games be imported between platforms? PC to console? Or even console to PC?

Comment: I'm going to go with no. But I have never actually tried it, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @GAThrawn Given the score my answer got (ill-deserved as it was) and the contest going on, it pains me to agree with you, but I think you're completely right.

Comment: @GAThrawn GAH! that didn't appear in the results when I searched. Maybe due to the title not including Mass Effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MassEffectSaves.com has a page dedicated](http://www.masseffectsaves.com/xbox.php) to how you can transfer saves from PC to XBox 360 and from 360 to PC. However, it doesn't appear you can do this with the PS3.

Comment: It says right on that page that you can go 360->PC.

Comment: @MBraedley Thanks, somehow I totally read that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, the save formats are not compatible. Here's a thread where users found no way to move PC saves to PS3 [ME2 save files from PC to PS3](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/103/index/4506347/1).

The main problem here is the PS3 and Xbox pair your save data with your user account, so for legal and practical reasons only saves made on PS3/Xbox normally work on those platforms. The PC save doesn't have that, so it would require some major hacking with the save file to get it to work.